# French accents encoding

Tags: php, mysql, ios, utf-8, mysqli

I have a database that contains some data in the French language, as you know, French contains some special characters like é, è, à, etc ...
In my case, I want to append an NSString (containing those special characters) in the url to make some treatment in the database, let's say that the NSString is : `Je suis très enerve` (notice the `è` character)
When doing what I'm using to do:

```
NSString *ana = [[arrayofAnalytics objectAtIndex:index] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I have this:

```
http://localhost/analytics/increment_ana.php?ana=je%20suis%20tr%C3%A8s%20enerve
```

The problem? Normally, `Je suis très enerve` NSString must be like this(I tested and the query executes):
`Je%20suis%20tr%E8s%20enerve` (%E8 and not %C3%A8).
My question is that function `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` does it solve the special French characters? If no, is there any other option? Do i have to manually replace the characters with their utf8 encoding characters?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It looks like simple urlencoding, so [urldecode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) should resolve it

Comment: @MarkBaker: do you mean that the iOS part is correct, but the problem is when receiving that URL in the server?

Comment: When that data was received by the server, it should have been urldecoded before inserting it into the database

Comment: The other question is what charset the data was sent to the server using, the best option is to use utf-8 consistently throughout, converting to utf-8 when necessary

Comment: @MarkBaker: all is UTF8, the database and the php files. I added `urldecode` but I have the same problem: changing %C3%A8 to %E8 solves the problem. So I think that `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` is the only valid choice.